# Display Apache 404 error in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, apache2, http-status-code-404

I want to display Apache 404 error in cakephp instead of displaying cakephp error. currently when controller is not found it displays cakephp applicationb with error I dont want to display cakephp application It show display apache error

Comment: @casperOne - bit left field, why has this question been closed (the question is pretty easy to understand)?

Comment: @AD7six "Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work."  We only got the last part, how it should work.

Comment: @AD7six Feel free to bring it up on [Meta].  The hold reason is explicit in what is lacking and why it was put on hold.  Make sure to disclose that you have involvement, as you have an answer (and rep) on the line.

Comment: @casperOne Actually everything requested is obvious. "What you've tried to do" = requesting a url that generates a 404 like /i/made/up; "Why it didn't work" = It generated a standard CakePHP error response; "How it should work" = by looking like an apache 404. Obviously the question could be improved; I don't think it deserves being closed by one opinion. I don't see the value in bringing this to meta, I've deleted my answer to disassociate my answer from these comments.

Answer (score 4):

To customize the content of a 404-error page and don't need custom logic, simply edit the contents of app/View/Errors/error400.ctp.

This seems not to be documented properly anywhere.